# Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно удалить значения в массиве оставив ключи

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно удалить значения в массиве оставив ключи, без всяких циклов.

Например есть такой массив:

```html
$array = [
  'one' => 1,
  'two' => 2,
  ...
];
```

Преобразовать его в такой:

```html
$array = [
   'one',
   'two',
   ...
];
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Ну и вернет он $array = [
   0 => 'one',
   1 => 'two',
   ...
]; А мне нужно без значений, только ключи

Comment: @Ololosha Вам к прочтению php.net.  

Массивы бывают только ассоциативные - как в первом примере, и нумерованные ' $array = [ 0 => 'one', 1 => 'two', ... ] ' И никак иначе.  

Возможно будет лучше описать цель которую вы хотите достичь таким поведением

Comment: Разойдись! `echo json_encode(array_keys($array));`

Comment: Как я понял, нужно очистить массив от значений. Тогда `array_fill_keys(array_flip($array),'');`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Оставить только ключи в массиве](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/234311/%d0%9e%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать функцию `array_keys($array)`

```
 array_keys($array)
```

Получить из массива, только кийс: `array_map`

```
$array = [
  'one' => 1,
  'two' => 2
];
$myarr = array_map(create_function('$n', 'return null;'), $array);
```

Comment: Вернет $array = [ 0 => 'one', 1 => 'two', ... ];  а мне нужно $array = [ 'one',  'two', ... ];

Comment: @Ololosha Прикол хотите `$array = [ 'one', 'two' ]; print_r($array);` возвращает `Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
)` потому что это одно и тоже. массивов совсем без ключей не бывает в природе. http://ideone.com/jEiMyR

Comment: я обновил код, теперь работает

Comment: Зачем было портить хороший ответ - не понимаю.

Comment: @Ипатьев Почему портить, чловек не получил ожидаемый ответ, я подправил

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался тупил как омежка..

Comment: А можно подробно, как разобрались?